# Query database for list of records intersecting with relational table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

Im trying to find a list of all movies that that contain 2 or **MORE** cast members in them.

```
select title from Movie where movieID in(
    select movieID
    from Cast
    join MovieHasCast
        on Cast.castID = MovieHasCast.castID
    where cast.name = 'gene wilder'
intersect
    select movieID
    from Cast
    join MovieHasCast
        on Cast.castID = MovieHasCast.castID
    where cast.name = 'richard pryor')
```

my alternative would be something like this:

```
select title from Movie where movieID in(
    select movieID
    from Cast
    join MovieHasCast
        on Cast.castID = MovieHasCast.castID
    where cast.name = 'gene wilder'
    and movieID in (
        select movieID
        from Cast
        join MovieHasCast
            on Cast.castID = MovieHasCast.castID
        where cast.name = 'richard pryor'))
```

This is just a sample of how I am accomplishing this.  However, I am building this query dynamically in C# to filter a list of movies by genre, cast members, etc.  I am concerned with performance.

**Is this the best way to accomplish this task?**  I feel like there is a better way to do this I just don't know how especially since a User could select 10 cast members and that query would start to get really large - even though it would likely return 0 records.

Comment: Can you post some example data and what should the result be? If I undestood you right just a single query with a group by will do

Comment: @JorgeCampos there are 15k+ cast members i couldnt post them, however be assured both these queries do return the correct result which is a list of titles where both Richard Prior and Gene Wilder star in them

Comment: Yeah I just ask for a some example like 3 rows of each table. But I think that @TI answer is what you want

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry - and yes, I agree I think after testing it looks like T I solution is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select movie.name
from movie
join moviehascast mc on mc.movieid = movie.id
join cast on cast.id = mc.castid
where cast.name in (@actor1, @actor2)
group by movie.name
having count(1) = @numberOfActorsSearched
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be the "simple" alternative I was looking for.  Do you think the performance on this is any less than the other two solutions I had posted?

Comment: I would think the performance of this would be better but you should check/compare the execution plans